Persist iSCSI RAM drive across reboots
To create a RAM disk on Windows Server, I used a tutorial at https://i12bretro.github.io/tutorials/0524.html and created a scheduled task with a powershell script, as suggested in its 2nd half.
Unfortunately, it does not work after a reboot.
First, the powershell command needed extra parameters, to run the script. This was trivial: -File was added to the task parameter box, and the script ran.
The problem is that not all commands in the script work:
New-IscsiVirtualDisk -Path "ramdisk:RAMDisk.vhdx" -Size 256MB

works reliably without issues, but
Add-IscsiVirtualDiskTargetMapping -TargetName RAMDisk -DevicePath "ramdisk:RAMDisk.vhdx"
Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter R -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "RAMDisk" -Confirm:$false

do not work. After a reboot, the drive does not exist.
Having tinkered with the above commands, I ended up splitting the powershell script into 3, with 1 command in each, and wrapping them in a CMD that redirects their output to separate log files. The 1st command outputs its diagnostics, the 2nd command does not output anything, and the 3d initially did not as well, until I added timeout /T 5 between each. Only then the 3d command began to work and output the new drive information. This introduced a 15 second delay for the creation of the RAM drive, which is unacceptable for many reasons.
Among the things that I tried was making the task conditional on the availability of network interfaces, but it only lead to the failures to start the task.
In the event log, I saw some errors re failures to reach iSCSI target on the IP address of the server's NIC. It sounds like the task tries to run too early, when iSCSI service has not yet started or started but not configured itself completely.
Is there a reliable way to persist an iSCSI RAM drive after a reboot, without having to resort to such tricks? If this is too difficult or involved, I can resort to a 3d party solution but prefers it to be built-in.

You don't mean for the data to persist, do you?
